# How to Force install the OFFLINE Update of CUMULATIVE UPDATE for WINDOWS 10 Version 1607 for X64-based Systems (KB4015438).?

Tags: windows, windows-update

I have an Offline installer for **Cumulative Update for Windows 10 Version 1607 for 64-based Systems (KB4015438)** which i download it in Windows 10 Cumulative Catalog Update link given from microsoft website. https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4015438
            OR
http://download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/software/updt/2017/03/windows10.0-kb4015438-x64_c0e4b528d1c6b75503efd12d44d71a809c997555.msu

My problem now is when i run this installer, It wont install to any 64bit of Windows 10 and says only to "Allow the program to RUN?" w/ an option tab of **RUN**  &  **CANCEL**  I click the RUN button tab and shows that it is executing for installation but it wont continue to install and with the error of  WINDOWS UPDATE STANDALONE INSTALLER ENCOUNTERED AND ERROR: 0X8007000d  The Data is invalid.

Comment: Looks like a corrupted file, try to re-DL it.

Answer (score 1):

The most common cause of this error message is your download being corrupted.

Check the digital certificate on `windows10.0-kb4015438-x64.msu` file. If it was not valid, download the file again. Here is how:

1. Right-click on `windows10.0-kb4015438-x64.msu` and select Properties.

   [image]
2. Click on "Digital Signature" tab. If no such tab exists, your download is corrupted. Download again.
3. Select one of the digital signatures, preferably the most stringent one. SHA512 is more stringent than SHA256, which is more stringent than SHA1.
4. Click on Details.
5. At the top of the "Digital Signature Details" dialog box, look for the verdict. If it does not say "The digital signature is OK" then download the file again.

   [image]

Comment: It also wouldn't hurt to re-download the file.

Comment: @harrymc The file is one freaking gigabyte. It does hurt.

Comment: @FleetCommand Then the author should wait until April 11 when the 1703 update is released

Comment: @Ramhound The OP is trying to install an update for 1607. Why must he wait for a version to which the update does not even apply?

Comment: Well it does apply because those cumulative updates are included in the first 1703 update, but I suggested that solution, as an alternative to downloading the update again.

Comment: Of course, in that case, the OP has to check the digital signature of the Creators Update. That's ~3.5 GB.